# Cambiar el connectionstring usando el archivo appsetting.json

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de consola con .Net Core con Entity Framework y quisiera configurar la conexión a base de datos usando la entrada del archivo appsetting.json.
En el mismo tengo esto:

"ConnectionStrings": {
        "Development": "Server=serverA\mssqlserver2014;Database=BASE1;User=sa;Password=xxx;",
        "WorkingHome": "Server=(localdb);Database=BASE2;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    }

Mi idea es alternar entre una conexión y la otra ("Development" o "WorkingHome"). 
Cómo debo hacer???

Aclaro que ya tengo el modelado en mi proyecto y en las dos bases las tengo iguales.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberias hacer variables Estaticas que le apuntes a una cadena u otra, segun lo que elijas al momento de compilar.

Comment: Ok, pero como configuro la connetionstring en tiempo de ejecución? Traerme el valor lo traigo pero... ¿Cómo lo asigno?

Comment: antes de hacer el CRUD y abrir la conexión deberías pasarle la cadena. Como haces la conexion?

Comment: En primera medida hice el scaffold-dbcontext server=..... database=... etc... ESto me hace el modelado de los datos en objetos. De esta manera puedo hacer CRUD sin problemas pero lo que quiero hacer ahora es poder cambiar de connectionstring rapidamente tocando el archivo appsetting.json. El dato de la conexión lo traigo sin problemas pero no se como debo proceder para establecerlo como conexión.

Comment: Resuelto!! Directamente le asigno lo que traigo desde el appsetting.json en el context. Era simple la cosa.... Muchas gracias Ramiro. Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto! Directamente le asigno lo que traigo desde el appsetting.json en el context.